# avoid complete check of an if statement

Tags: delphi

The code sample below should evaluate an string.

```
function EvaluateString(const S: Ansistring): Ansistring;
var
  i, L: Integer;
begin
  L := Length(S);
  i:=1;
  if (L > 0) and (S[i] > ' ') and (S[L] > ' ') then
     .....


end;
```

but if L=0  then `(S[i] > ' ')` will create an Access violation. 
Can I avoid this problem while keeping the `if` condition?

Comment: Did you enable complete boolean eval?

Comment: What David means is that if complete boolean evaluation is *not* enabled (this is the default), you won't get the access violation, since, if `L = 0`, the test for `(L > 0)` will already fail and make the code skip the rest of the evaluation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to either put a `{$B-}` statement on top of your code, or enable [boolean short circuit evaluation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirsbooleanshortcircuitevaluation_xml.html) in the project settings.

Since `{$B-}` is the default, you may have already turned it on before, or there is a `{$B+}` directive somewhere that is turning it off.

In the **short circuit evaluation** mode `{$B-}`, Delphi creates code that is (roughly) equivalent to this:

```
 if (L > 0) then begin
    if (S[i] > ' ') then begin        
       if (S[L] > ' ') then begin     
          .....
       end;
    end;
 end;
```

In contrast, with **full boolean evaluation** mode `{$B+}`, the equivalent could be something like this:

```
 var a,b,c : Boolean;

 a := (L > 0);
 b := (S[i] > ' ');  // always executed
 c := (S[L] > ' ');  // always executed

 if a and b and c then .....
```